# URL composition when passing variables

Tags: php, url, search, filepath

How do you pass a variable to another page with a URL like the one below?

```
www.domain.com/results?search_query=test
```

Instead of like this:

```
www.domain.com/results/?search_query=test
```

(referring to the slash after "results")

I think the first URL looks nicer, but each time I try to have it that way on my site, it automatically puts a slash in.

Currently, my file path looks like so `root>results>index.php` (file that I pass the variable to)

Comment: Have you tried using `.htaccess`?

Comment: In what way? @phplover I've never really had to dabble with htaccess files. What would I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a folder called `results` with `index.php` inside it, make a php file called `results.php` in the root directory.

Then using `.htaccesss` file, you can rewrite the link to fit to what you would like.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1.php
```